# Python: how to write to stdin of a subprocess and read its output in real time

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio, stdout, stdin

I have 2 programs.

The first (which could be written in any language, actually and therefore cannot be altered at all) looks like this:

```py
#!/bin/env python3

import random

while True:
    s = input()  # get input from stdin
    i = random.randint(0, len(s))  # process the input
    print(f"New output {i}", flush=True)  # prints processed input to stdout
```

It runs forever, read something from `stdin`, processes it and writes the result to `stdout`.

I am trying to write a second program in Python using the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library.
It executes the first program as a subprocess and attempt to feed it input via its `stdin` and retrieve the result from the its `stdout`.

Here is my code so far:

```py
#!/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import asyncio.subprocess as asp


async def get_output(process, input):
    out, err = await process.communicate(input)
    print(err) # shows that the program crashes
    return out

    # other attempt to implement

    process.stdin.write(input)
    await process.stdin.drain()  # flush input buffer

    out = await process.stdout.read()  # program is stuck here
    return out


async def create_process(cmd):
    process = await asp.create_subprocess_exec(
        cmd, stdin=asp.PIPE, stdout=asp.PIPE, stderr=asp.PIPE)
    return process


async def run():
    process = await create_process("./test.py")

    out = await get_output(process, b"input #1")
    print(out) # b'New output 4'
    out = await get_output(process, b"input #2")
    print(out) # b''
    out = await get_output(process, b"input #3")
    print(out) # b''
    out = await get_output(process, b"input #4")
    print(out) # b''

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(run())

asyncio.run(main())
```

I struggle to implement the `get_output` function. It takes a bytestring (as needed by the `input` parameter of the `.communicate()` method) as parameter, writes it to the `stdin` of the program, reads the response from its `stdout` and returns it.

Right now, only the first call to `get_output` works properly. This is because the implementation of the `.communicate()` method calls the `wait()` method, effectively causing the program to terminate (which it isn't meant to). This can be verified by examining the value of `err` in the `get_output` function, which shows the first program reached `EOF`. And thus, the other calls to `get_output` return an empty bytestring.

I have tried another way, even less successful, since the program gets stuck at the line `out = await process.stdout.read()`. I haven't figured out why.

My question is how do I implement the `get_output` function to capture the program's output in (near) real time and keep it running ? It doesn't have to be using `asyncio`, but I have found this library to be the best one so far for that.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Is the first program guaranteed to print only one line of output in response to the line of input that it has read? If so, you can change `await process.stdout.read()` to `await process.stdout.readline()` and your second approach should work. (It's now stuck because it is trying to read everything until EOF, and your first program never exits, so EOF never happens.)

Comment: And if the first program is not guaranteed to print only one line of output, then it's not clear how this _could_ be implemented, since there is no way to know how much data to read.

Comment: @user4815162342  `.read(n)` and `.readline()` don't work. No `.read*()` method seem to work, actually. Would there be a way to [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) the output ?

Comment: I think I've now found the issue in your code - see the posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first program is guaranteed to print only one line of output in response to the line of input that it has read, you can change `await process.stdout.read()` to `await process.stdout.readline()` and your second approach should work.

The reason it didn't work for you is that your `run` function has a bug: it never sends a newline to the child process. Because of that, the child process is stuck in `input()` and never responds. If you add `\n` at the end of the bytes literals you're passing to `get_output`, the code works correctly.

Comment: Holy shit, how I do I have to be to miss something like that ? Thanks! Do you know how I could use `.read()` or an equivalent to read as many bytes as I can until the next prompt ?

Comment: @Haltarys There is no way to do that. `read()` reads until EOF, and for `read(n)` or `readexactly(n)` (`read(n)` can return less than *n* bytes) you need to know the *n*. You could invent a protocol where the child program somehow announces how many bytes it is going to write, or use a self-delimiting encoding, etc., but those will require modifying it, which you said is off limits. The best approach will depend on the precise constraints.